# How to match certain properties of objects or certain elements of arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to match objects with certain properties or arrays with certain elements like this:

Now I am getting a compilation error, how can I implement this?

```
type Pos = [number, number]

type STAR = "*"
type LITERAL<A> = A
type Matcher<A> = STAR | LITERAL<A>

function match<A>(s: A, m: Matcher<A>): boolean {
   if (m === "*") {
       return true;
   } else {
       return s === m;
   }
}

function match2(b: Pos, q: Matcher<Pos>): boolean {
    return match(b[0], q[0]) && match(b[1], q[1]);
}

const poss: Pos[] = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]]

let res = poss.filter(_ => match2(_, [1, "*"])) // [[1, 1], [1, 2]]

console.log(res);
```

The properties of items and the query item given as literal are referentially equal.

### Edit

The provided solution worked, now I want to do nested queries like this:

```
  interface Pos2 {
    file: string,
    rank: string
  }

  interface Board {
    p1: Pos2,
    p2: Pos2
  }

  function match3<A>(b: A, q: MapMatcher<A>): boolean {
   if (typeof b === 'object' && typeof q === 'object') {
    for (let key in b) {
      if (!match(q[key], b[key])) {
        return false;
       }
     }
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
  }

  let a2 = {
      file: "a",
      rank: "2"
  }, a3 = {
      file: "a",
      rank: "3"
  }, b1 = {
      file: "b",
      rank: "1"
  }, b2 = {
      file: "b",
      rank: "2"
  };

  let poss2 = [a2,a3,b1,b2]

  let boards = [{
      p1: a2,
      p2: a3
  }, {
      p1: a2,
      p2: b1
  }, {
      p1: a3,
      p2: b2
  }]

  function query<A>(arr: A[], m: MapMatcher<A>): A[] {
      return arr.filter(_ => match3(_, m));
  }

   let q1 = query(poss2, {
          file: "a",
          rank: "*"
      })

  // nested equality
  query(boards, {
      p1: q1,
      p2: "*"
  });

  // reference equality
  match3(boards, {
      p1: a2,
      p2: "*"
  })
```

The above code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

`Matcher<Pos>` is not the appropriate type for the `q` argument of `match2()`.  If you inspect it, that type is equivalent to:

```
 type MatcherPos = "*" | [number, number]
```

You cannot pass `[1, "*"]`  into something that expects `"*" | [number, number]`.  That's why you get the following error:

```
let res = poss.filter(_ => match2(_, [1, "*"])) // error!
//                                   ~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '[number, string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Matcher<Pos>'.
```

---

Presumably you don't want `Matcher<Pos>`, but something like `MapMatcher<Pos>` where `MapMatcher<T>` takes an object/array type `T` and maps each property `T[K]` and maps it to `Matcher<T[K]>`:

```
type MapMatcher<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Matcher<T[K]> }
```

Applying that to `Pos` yields a type equivalent to:

```
type MapMatcherPos = [Matcher<number>, Matcher<number>];
```

or

```
type MapMatcherPos = ["*" | number, "*" | number];
```

---

If I make that change,

```
function match2(b: Pos, q: MapMatcher<Pos>): boolean {
    return match(b[0], q[0]) && match(b[1], q[1]);
}
```

then everything compiles now:

```
let res = poss.filter(_ => match2(_, [1, "*"])) // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgewM4wLwwNoDsCuBbAIygCcAaGXQkgXWFElgGUAVAQQCU0YAiAKm-rQYAGQCSzAKLtWwgDysAfF1aDYAWQCGIAMYALEvKXoWHGAB8R4qTMN0AZjizaQASwRYYeLXsMAKJABcMKzkeEGaOvrEhgCUQQQICAA2UBoeAN7AMNkwLnYwvnhoqOh83DEwmTnVMMRQIDjEHiDEOFAA3Fk5AL4wUElIsFU12XUNTTAoJeh4ndXdwAuqMBIAHhBpACayzEYwzH2rIFBYmyguWHYkMADyMAD8lZgA0rkeANZQYAj5N9RBaw2p1kNwwz2oSl6QSwUAAbiQ6OAhBE9CREFMVustrIUVFZOiFApOgB6YkwJHqbxRdFcMrmTCUIhkCj4Jm0REMGCaCC4gy7LjpF5vGCfb75Zj-LlUvlgiEwBYUqU86XEGnoQHY7m86IEonAUnkzlalVqzDa2SMkgKcjmy3EBTshxOVzuTxUgBMvgIQXR5AAjuENMrIgYCXEYAlkqkMl1RvVGh4vJEvRgAAzUf1p6gVABkObdyYIGAAjBmYH6S9nOkttO4kCAYBBkIF4MgMNQuBgS+RS+RuzB3WWMO6e9R2SkG3UMU2kEgAHR2FxJY7EXwAfTQSiTek9a77xfIZWzFQNXYPMF7mHPg-ZBoQxBcAHMLhokn1iMR7wF9WSRn--wB1QAH4gaBIE-sExCPvgJwNj8hpCAA5NgrIkOQ9YPlgj7UIhuQoFgCANhos5PlgGgECk5III2GjEBoeD1Nc8GKoh5oEohc50LWWBIFGc5JAgj6+FOMTtEAA)